# on mouseover animate margin and animate back without mouseout

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i m trying to animate a image on mouse over and i want that it animate back to it normal position without using mouseout.

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
$("#bysti-menu li").mouseover(function(){

                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('.uprmenuicon')
                      .animate({
                        'margin-top':'-40px'

                     },400,'easeOutBack').animate({
                        'margin-top':'0px'

                     },400,'easeOutBack')
}).mouseout(function(){
  // do nothing
});
```

});

here when i put mouseover the image its margin becomes -40px but i want that immediately after that it becomes normal to 0px even when mouse is not yet out ? can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up your function to listen for what type of event is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/dn9wD/1/

Comment: well this one is working but my image is  bouncing back many times is this because i have 6 images of same class ?any sol for tht

Comment: add `queue: false` after duration

Comment: thanks it does the job little bit but still suppose the image is of width 60px and my mouse is on left side of image . when i hover it to left side it animates and stops like i wanted ,but if my mouse moves little right it starts animating again n again ? why so? i am accepting this answer already as its a huge help thank u

Comment: No problem, glad I could help some! Are you trying to set it so that it only animates once? Or are you trying to reduce the sensitivity of the hover area?

Comment: well wanted to inform you friend solved that issue by using mouse enter and mouse leave instead of using over

Comment: well i was trying to reduce the sensitivity of the hover area , i found a solution for it  by using mouse enter . any more gud ideas?

Comment: You could look into using setTimeout() with a variable as some sort of temporary off switch, give it a shot, but if you have trouble with that I would post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

jquery .animate() has a "complete" parameter that is called once the animation is completed.  Check the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: i have but still its not working i want the height back to 0px without mouseout

Comment: Hiya I reckon `.stop` will do the trick to stop animation see demo below `:)`

Answer (score 0):

**Sample demo** http://jsfiddle.net/R4bzf/ (Behaviour: drag mouse over the yellow/orange panel and then do mouseout)

API `.stop` will do the trick http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Hope this helps, please let me know if I missed anything, thanx

**code**

```
$(this).stop() // Do whatever - .animate({ left: "-270" }, 500);
```

Comment: friend thanks for the jsfiddle example . but u see when i am moving my mouse of that div then is returning to normal . i want that it animates once like left: "-270" and at the same time returns to 0px automatically without me moving my mouse out of that div .

Comment: @SakshiSharma Hiya `:)` ummmm, can you flick a sample demo I might be able to help you out, thanks, < bit hard to understand the scenario >

Comment: well @eivers88 got it working the way i wanted but for 6 images of same class its animating image more then one time on mouseover any sol to tht

Comment: @SakshiSharma no worries, `B-)` see you around!